# Does it make sense to use Newton-Raphson learning rate in Stochastic Gradient Descent?

Tags: optimization, newton-raphson, gradient-descent

[Stochastic gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) descent updates with learning rate $\eta$ as follows $$w:=w-\eta \nabla f_i(w),$$ where $f_i(w)$ is the objective function evaluated at one data point. SG than iterates over randomly selected data points until convergence but with constant learning rate.

An advantage of Newton-Raphson is that the learning rate is determined by the Hessian $H(w)$ leading to update rule $$w:=w-H(w) \nabla f(w),$$ where $f(w)$ is usually evaluated across all data points. This turns NR typically more efficient than gradient descent.

It seems it would make most sense to combine both methods to $$w:=w-H(w) \nabla f_i(w).$$ Are there strong arguments against doing so or why do I never see this done (my context is statistics / machine learning)?

Comment: The matrix is too big. But quasi-Newton methods are used, esp. BFGS and its limited memory variant.

Comment: @LutzL which matrix is too big and why?

Comment: Since you are talking about machine learning, I assumed lots of free parameters in $w$ that would have to be tuned. And a correspondingly large number of learning samples. The Jacobian of $(f(w,x_i)-y_i)$ for Gauss-Newton resp. the Hessean of $\sum_i|f(w,x_i)-y_i|^2$ for Newton on the gradient, both for $w$, will be large matrices.

Comment: @LutzL Good point. So irrespective of this, it should work. So e.g. if I have not so many free parameters but large sample size it seems like a viable alternative?

Comment: I believe Gauß-Newton is easier, esp. as it does not need second derivatives. I think it it possible to continuously update the QR decomposition of the Jacobian, so that there is no memory problem. Note that the higher the dimension, the localer the Newton method. Doing a line-search or a scaling of the Newton step with the scaling parameter growing whenever an error reduction is achieved is probably required.